# Selenium grid Console showing "[/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused"

Tags: appium, selenium-grid

Please refer to attached screen shot. I've registed 2 emulators to Selenium HUB ( started appium server for each of them )

But it's showing this error message, I'm not sure what does it mean ? Is there something I'm doing wrong ?

Please clarify

[image: Selenium Grid Console with 2 appium emulators registered]

To keep it simple I tried launching HUB and registering appium nodes from command line

I got below output from command line

```
appium --nodeconfig EMULATOR_Nexus_4_1.json  
[Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.6.3 
[Appium] Non-default server args:  
[Appium]   nodeconfig: 'EMULATOR_Nexus_4_1.json' 
[debug] [Appium] Starting auto register thread for grid. Will try to register every 5000 ms. 
[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723 
[debug] [Appium] Appium successfully registered with the grid on localhost:4444
```

But on hub console, still seeing same error per screen shot. Not sure what may be going wrong here ?

Comment: Need to see node config files. Are nodes launched on the same machine?

Comment: @KristapsMežavilks you were right, node config was wrong. I could get it working now.  Currently doing POC on single mac pro but would like to run them on linux container with each one running single instance of android emulator.  Did you try this setup ? Any open project to refer to will be helpful . Thanks in advance

Comment: Happy to help you. No I have not used this setup and I do not think that this is necessary as Android can handle multiple devices on single machine (I have tested with 4 devices). iOS is a little bit different, so I am using MAC OS virtual machines. Good luck.
P.S. Mark your answer as the correct answer so it is not in 'unanswered' list.

Comment: Thanks for info. I need to wait for 2 days to mark as correct answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

node config file entry was wrong earlier.

Worked with below

```
{"capabilities":[{"browserName":"Nexus_4_1","version":"4.4.2","maxInstances":1,"platform":"ANDROID"}],"configuration":{"nodeTimeout":120,"port":4723,"hubPort":4444,"proxy":"org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy","hubHost":"127.0.0.1", "nodePolling":2000, "registerCycle":10000,"register":true,"cleanUpCycle":2000,"timeout":30000,"maxSession":1}}
```

Refereed to http://www.vimalselvam.com/2016/05/15/selenium-grid-for-appium-mobile-automation/